# Duplicating rows of excel data

Tags: excel, duplicates, rows

This macro works great for duplicating rows based on an integer value in a specific column.  How do I get it to also copy the formatting of the original data?

```
Sub DuplicateRows()

Dim currentRow As Integer
Dim currentNewSheetRow As Integer: currentNewSheetRow = 1

For currentRow = 1 To 3 'The last row of your data

    Dim timesToDuplicate As Integer
    timesToDuplicate = CInt(Sheet1.Range("D" & currentRow).Value2)

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To timesToDuplicate

        Sheet2.Range("A" & currentNewSheetRow).Value2 = Sheet1.Range("A" & currentRow).Value2
        Sheet2.Range("B" & currentNewSheetRow).Value2 = Sheet1.Range("B" & currentRow).Value2
        Sheet2.Range("C" & currentNewSheetRow).Value2 = Sheet1.Range("C" & currentRow).Value2

        currentNewSheetRow = currentNewSheetRow + 1

    Next i

Next currentRow

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Have you tried the most obvious solution of just copying the cell over to the new row ?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t quite understand what you are trying to accomplish but when I want to copy everything (format, value etc.) I use the Copy and PasteSpecial functions of a cell.

```
Sub DuplicateRows()

Dim currentRow As Integer
Dim currentNewSheetRow As Integer: currentNewSheetRow = 1

For currentRow = 1 To 3 'The last row of your data

    Dim timesToDuplicate As Integer
    timesToDuplicate = CInt(Sheet1.Range("D" & currentRow).Value2)

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To timesToDuplicate

        Sheet1.Range("A" & currentNewSheetRow).Copy
        Sheet2.Range("A" & currentRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
        Sheet1.Range("B" & currentNewSheetRow).Copy
        Sheet2.Range("B" & currentRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
        Sheet1.Range("C" & currentNewSheetRow).Copy
        Sheet2.Range("C" & currentRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

        currentNewSheetRow = currentNewSheetRow + 1

    Next i

Next currentRow

End Sub
```

Also look at the posible parameters for the PasteSpecial function to accomplish your result.